# How to save Html table data in .txt file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my Html Table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email Id</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Prefered Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Miles</td>
      <td>james@abcd.com</td>
      <td>9876543210</td>
      <td>email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Paul</td>
      <td>john@abcd.com</td>
      <td>9638527410</td>
      <td>phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Math</td>
      <td>willams</td>
      <td>Math@abcd.com</td>
      <td>99873210456</td>
      <td>phone</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this table there is Save Button.

```
<input type="button" id="txt" value="Save" />
```

Button Code

```
function tableToJson(table) {
  var data=[];
  var headers=[];
  for (var i=0;
  i < table.rows[0].cells.length;
  i++) {
    headers[i]=table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '');
  }
  for (var i=1;
  i < table.rows.length;
  i++) {
    var tableRow=table.rows[i];
    var rowData= {}
    ;
    for (var j=0;
    j < tableRow.cells.length;
    j++) {
      rowData[headers[j]]=tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
    }
    data.push(rowData);
  }
  return data;
}
```

When the click the save button, The html table data will stored in the .txt document without `<table>`,`<tr>`,`<td>`. The data storing format will be like  below format.

```
(James,Miles,james@abcd.com,9876543210,email),
(John,Paul,john@abcd.com,9638527410,phone),
(Math,willams,Math@abcd.com,99873210456,phone)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: But where exactly is you problem, what is the line or expression that does not work / you need help with?

Comment: i need to save html table data's in the .txt file without <td> and <tr> and <table> tags.

Comment: @BA-T yes you've already said that. But then you posted some code that looks like an attempt. So...we need to know, what are you stuck on exactly? Does some part of it not work, specifically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slightly clearer code than the above answer that works for any number of columns

```
var retContent = [];
var retString = '';
$('tbody tr').each(function (idx, elem)
{
  var elemText = [];
  $(elem).children('td').each(function (childIdx, childElem)
  {
    elemText.push($(childElem).text());
  });
  retContent.push(`(${elemText.join(',')})`);
});
retString = retContent.join(',\r\n');
```

[jsfiddle with the full code](https://jsfiddle.net/chehmhuz/2/)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to create data which contains all `user` details.

```
userDetails='';
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
   var detail='(';
   $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        detail+=$(this).html()+',';
   });
   detail=detail.substring(0,detail.length-1);
   detail+=')';
   userDetails+=detail+"\r\n";
});
```

Then you need to save file:

```
var a=document.getElementById('save');
a.onclick=function(){
    var a = document.getElementById("save");
    var file = new Blob([userDetails], {type: 'text/plain'});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = "data.txt";
}
```

Here is a working solution: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrgxmdyt/6/).

Comment: thanks its working but () only missing that i added.

Comment: and , also missing so only